# How to run specific task from grunt.registerTask()?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gruntjs, mean-stack

I have registered tasks with grunt as below -

```
grunt.registerTask('regenerateSources', ['clean:local', 'bower', 'uglify']);
```

As I am using `grunt regenerateSources` command to run above tasks i.e. clean, bower and uglify. Is there any way/command to run only `uglify` task in my case ?

Comment: I had the same issue but instead I m using gulp. What I did was to create sub tasks and call them in the master task. So i can call them seperate. Like `grunt do-uglify`

Comment: Yes right, I am also keeping that option as a work around. Till then lets see if there is any actual command exists for it.

Answer (score 3):

That was me being silly, working on grunt tasks for the first time. Simple command as  `grunt uglify` works as charm.

Hope it will be helpful for other newbie's who might run into same.